# How to make 2 letters as two different colors in Android xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout, keyboard

I want to make a key which consists in two characters and I want to make those two characters differently colored.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `HTML.fromHtml()` or the `Spannable` class. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String first = "H";
String next = "<font color='#EE0000'>I</font>";
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(first + next));
```